# How to configure ssl on express

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I am trying to configure ssl in express with the following configuration but I keep on getting errors and I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

```
 use strict';

//dependencies
var config = require('./config'),
    //uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    https = require('https');


//create express app
var app = express();


//keep reference to config
app.config = config;


app.server = https.createServer(app.config.ssl_options, app);


//listen u
app.server.listen(443);
```

Here is how I am importing the config files, the config files are placed in config.js

```
exports.ssl_options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./2b62bb384fb2b9.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt')
};
```

Here are my errors

```
    events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/app.js:100:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

The line that I am getting the errors is

```
//listen u
app.server.listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're binding to a port < 1024, you have to use `sudo` to start your server because only privileged users (root) can bind to those ports.